# java - where to put the configuration files

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am writing java application. I am using Spring MVC, Spring Security, Hibernate and Tiles. I am using maven in my project. Whenever I execute my web app I get an exception:

```
0 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
281 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Feb 04 03:15:50 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
625 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/security-app-context.xml]
640 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [resources/security-app-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/security-app-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at ...........
    ..............
```

I tried to put my security-app-context.xml anywhere but it doesn;t help and I keep getting this exception.

Here is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>success.green-wheels</groupId>
    <artifactId>green-wheels-project</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>web-app-module</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.apache.tiles.version>2.2.2</org.apache.tiles.version>
        <org.hibernate.version>3.3.2.GA</org.hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        ...Some dependencies to Spring, Hibernate and so
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/success/greenWheels/dataAccess/hibernate/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                  <webResources>
                    <resource>
                      <directory>web</directory>
                    </resource>
                  </webResources>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my directory structure:
[image]

What is wrong? Where should I put the security-app-context.xml in order to make it work?

I want to put all the configuration files in one folder. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/security-app-context.xml]
```

How did you get this exeption? Where is your `resources` folder? I don't see it...

Did you use `<import resource="resources/security-app-context.xml" />` in Spring config? If yes, I guess you have to use `<import resource="security-app-context.xml" />`.

I'm not sure about `IntelliJ IDEA`, but in `SpringSource Tool Suite` (or `Eclipse`, doesn't matter) my `Maven` project has structure like this:

[image: SpringSource Tool Suite Maven project structure]

Answer (score 1):

The `/resources` directory will be in the `CLASSPATH` if you put it under `WEB-INF/classes`.